# Proper way to construct linq queries to achieve fastest performance?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generic-list

Similar question have been asked here but none fits to my need.
I made test cases to see which is faster. But I feel my linq code is still slow. How do I construct the linq code for faster performance?

Others said using double `.Tolist()` can cause slower operation, when I test it, it shows that it is faster than any other tests.

Test:

```
Preparation
---------------------------------------------------------------
return Properties of UserInfo(userinf, true){
    UserID = userinf.UserID;
    FirstName = userinf.user.FirstName;
    MiddleName = userinf.user.MiddleName;
    LastName = userinf.user.LastName;
    LoginID = userinf.user.LoginID;
    Birthday = userinf.Birthday;
}

skip = 0;
take = 100;

total table records = 304;

Linq to Entity Framework
```

Fiddler: v2.4.0.0

```
https://127.0.0.1/..../RetrieveUserInfo?skip=0&take=100
{
    "client":{
        "SessionID":"5433ab64-7e0d-444f-b886-a901ea9a0601"
    },
    "session":{
        "SessionID":"35b75daa-25ad-45a4-9f99-0e69ec3b66a4"
    }
}
```

---

```
//Test 1
//1) 00:00:15.3068755 -- Attempt1
//2) 00:00:13.8207905 -- Attempt2
//3) 00:00:16.2489294 -- Attempt3

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes
            select usr).OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

userlist = (from i in list
            select new UserInfo(i, true)).ToList();


///Test 2
//1) 00:00:15.3908803
//2) 00:00:14.8818512
//3) 00:00:19.4761140

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList()
            select new UserInfo(usr, true)).ToList();


//Test 3
//1) 00:00:30.1937270
//2) 00:00:24.1003784
//3) 00:00:28.8806519

var list = dbase.userinfoes.OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
userlist = (from i in list select new UserInfo(i, true)).ToList();


//Test 4
//1) 00:00:57.2652754
//2) 00:00:54.4051118
//3) 00:00:55.3251644

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes
            select usr).ToList();

userlist = (from i in list
            select new UserInfo(i, true)).OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();


//Test 5
//1) 00:01:06.8378229
//2) 00:01:01.2845053
//3) 00:00:55.0721499

var list = from usr in dbase.userinfoes
           select usr;

userlist = (from i in list.AsEnumerable()
            select new UserInfo(i, true)).OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();


// Test 6
// VERY LONG. It tooks all records first and construct UserInfo one by one before doing the skip and take

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable()
            select new UserInfo(usr, true)).OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();


//Test 7
// VERY LONG. It tooks all records first and construct UserInfo one by one before doing the skip and take

var list = from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable()
           select new UserInfo(usr);
```

Proper code for faster search. Thanks to `casperOne` for pointing out that **the ordering, skip and take are all performed on the server** is more faster.

Here is the final code:

```
var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes
                .OrderBy(i => i.UserID)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .AsEnumerable()
            select new UserInfo(usr, true)).ToList();   

1) 00:00:10.9210513
2) 00:00:10.8270973
3) 00:00:10.8250151
```

Thanks to `Richard Neil Ilagan` for the final code.

Comment: I've got some doubts on how the tests are implemented. Anyway there is a long, long post that address this sort of problems: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm reading it now.

Comment: You should probably post the benchmark code as well since those results do not seem to make a lot of sense. For example, test 1 and 3 are very similar except that there is an extra call to `Select` in test 1, but 3 takes twice as long.

Comment: I dont know which code is better, but as you said test 1 and 3 were the same, is it also the same when it comes to performance at the same time achieving same result of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's why each one is performing as it is and why you're seeing what you're seeing:

**Test 1:**

```
///Test 2
//1) 00:00:15.3068755 -- Attempt1
//2) 00:00:13.8207905 -- Attempt2
//3) 00:00:16.2489294 -- Attempt3

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes
            select usr).OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

userlist = (from i in list
            select new UserInfo(i, true)).ToList();
```

This is absolutely the fastest.  It's the fastest because the ordering, skip and take are all performed on the server.  Because you probably have indexes, the server is beefy (powerful), etc. it can handle these operations much faster than if you materialized the whole set on the client and then performed the operations there.

`UserInfo` constructed only on the post-processed list.

**Test 2:**

```
///Test 2
//1) 00:00:15.3908803
//2) 00:00:14.8818512
//3) 00:00:19.4761140

var list = (
    from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable().
        OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList()
    select new UserInfo(usr, true)
).ToList();
```

This *should* have a performance impact the same as test 7; the call to [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is forcing all subsequent operations to be performed in memory (and the call to [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) is going to require you to materialize all of the instances before they're ordered).

This is a bit if an anomaly.  I'd be curious to see what the SQL sent to the server is (assuming you're using SQL server or some SQL-based back end), to make sure that it's selecting all the records back.

`UserInfo` constructed only on the post-processed list.

**Test 3:**

```
//Test 3
//1) 00:00:30.1937270
//2) 00:00:24.1003784
//3) 00:00:28.8806519

var list = dbase.userinfoes.OrderBy(i => i.UserID).
    Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
userlist = (from i in list select new UserInfo(i, true)).ToList();
```

Again, the order by, skip, and take are taking place on the server.  You're materializing the list twice (you have two calls to `ToList`), which is the only explanation for the overhead I can see).

`UserInfo` constructed only on the post-processed list.

**Test 4:**

```
//Test 4
//1) 00:00:57.2652754
//2) 00:00:54.4051118
//3) 00:00:55.3251644

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes
            select usr).ToList();

userlist = (from i in list select new UserInfo(i, true)).
    OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

You're materializing the entire list in memory now, so there's more overhead now.

`UserInfo` constructed on the pre-processed list.

**Test 5:**

```
//Test 5
//1) 00:01:06.8378229
//2) 00:01:01.2845053
//3) 00:00:55.0721499

var list = from usr in dbase.userinfoes
           select usr;

userlist = (from i in list.AsEnumerable()
            select new UserInfo(i, true)).
    OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Same as test two, you're doing all the operations on the client side.

`UserInfo` constructed on the pre-processed list.

**Test 6:**

```
// Test 6
// VERY LONG. It tooks all records first and construct 
// UserInfo one by one before doing the skip and take

var list = (from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable()
            select new UserInfo(usr, true)).
    OrderBy(i => i.UserID).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

`UserInfo` constructed on the pre-processed list.

Again, doing all the operations on the client side.

```
// Test 7
// VERY LONG. It tooks all records first and construct 
// UserInfo one by one before doing the skip and take

var list = from usr in dbase.userinfoes.AsEnumerable()
           select new UserInfo(usr);
```

Again, doing all the operations on the client side.

`UserInfo` constructed on the pre-processed list.

There is *one* difference I notice in all of these tests, and that's where you call the constructor for the `UserInfo` instance.  In the places where the performance is good, you put off constructing the instance of `UserInfo` as late as possible (after you perform order, take, skip operations), whereas when the performance is bad, you're constructing the `UserInfo` instance up front, before these operations take place (when there is usually more calls to the `UserInfo` constructor).

That said, it would seem that your performance issues *could* lie within the constructor for the `UserInfo` class, and not in LINQ.  Generally, when you let the [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) provider perform the operations on the underlying data source, it's *generally* faster than doing those operations in memory on the client.

Without seeing the constructor code though, it's impossible to tell, but your numbers certainly suggest that the problem lies there, and not in LINQ.