# Does using Take improve the performance

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

If I have a `LINQ to Entities` query that returns some results, does using `Take` improve the performance? I mean because at the end of the query we are saying `.Take(thisManyRecords)` then does it first return all the records and then just returns back to me `thisManyRecords` or it really from beginning limits its search to `thisManyRecords`?

Comment: My database isn't big enough so I can actually test this myself and feel the difference.

Comment: This is covered a lot elsewhere, have you searched around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062462/proper-way-to-construct-linq-queries-to-achieve-fastest-performance ...for instance.

Comment: Write the code both ways. Run the code both ways. Now you know which is faster.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, that is unless you've made some [performance benchmarking mistakes](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one)

Comment: If your database isn't big enough to run meaningful performance tests then **get a bigger database**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to entities implies EF and some provider that gets queries.

You dont need bags of data to check. SQL profiler will show the SQL statement used.

If you apply `.Take` to an IQueryable source. You end up with an Expression tree and this can be sent to db ;

Context.Set().Where(t => ??).OrderBy(t => t.??).Take(n);

results in TOP(n) being sent.

IF you however force the enumeration eg .ToList()   and the did .Take() then this applies to the memory objects and is not sent to DB.

[Query Execution in EF explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)